# How do I create a new object if the condition is true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I want to add the values associated with the arrayOpportunityCategory(An array containing comma separated strings and is part of a JSON object) to a new object/array if a user inputted value is in arrayOpportunityCategory.

So far, I have this:

```
const category = _.forOwn(res.body, function(val, key){
      const arrayOpportunityCategory = val.category.split(" ")
      if(arrayOpportunityCategory.indexOf(interest.raw) > -1){
        const suggestedOpportunity = []
        suggestedOpportunity.push(val)
      } else {
        console.log('Sorry, we have nothing of that sort.')
      }
    })

  }
```

Comment: Consider this: `const suggestedOpportunity = []`. Every time you do this, you're creating a new empty array. You then add a value to it and then, voila, your array is gone. Where do you think you should declare `suggestedOpportunity` if you want it to persist?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const suggestedOpportunity = []
const category = _.forOwn(res.body, function(val, key){
      const arrayOpportunityCategory = val.category.split(" ")
      if(arrayOpportunityCategory.indexOf(interest.raw) > -1){    
        suggestedOpportunity.push(val)
      } else {
        console.log('Sorry, we have nothing of that sort.')
      }
    })    
  }
```

Declare your `suggestedOpprtunity array outside of your loop`, else you would end up having creating a new array for each `iteration` and finally you would have only the last values.